# Drawing a line between points on ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

My graph shown below will create a simple point scatter graph. I am trying to add a line between points, (3,45)-(4,40), and then a seperate line between points (2,108)-(3,45)-(3,118)-(4,91)-(4,104), and another between (3,45)-(4,40).

I think it has to do with adding more grouping and the a geom_line. However, I am a bit stuck.

Any help would be great.

```
x<-c(2,3,4,3,4,4)
w<-c(108,114,104,45,91,40)
wts<-data.frame(x,w)
h <- ggplot(data=wts, aes(x,w))
h <- h + geom_point(colour="blue")
h <- h + labs(title="Breaches",x = "Quarter", y= "Number of Breaches")
h<-h + theme_minimal()
h<-h + xlim(1,5)
h<-h + ylim(0,120)
h
```

Comment: Could you include a sample of the expected plot? It's clearer to understand(in my opinion).

Comment: geom_segment() should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to provide *new* data to subsequent calls to `geom_path`. Since you're talking about connecting points in the original frame, I don't think it's necessary to make a new frame, just index which columns we want. One nice thing (with `ggplot2`) here is that the aesthetics (`aes(x,w)`) are unchanged (though updating them along with `data=` is not a problem).

```r
h +
  geom_path(data=wts[c(4,6),], color="blue") +
  geom_path(data=wts[c(1,4,2,5,3),], color="red")
```

I think you mis-typed one of your coordinates, should `(3,118)` be `(3,114)`? If not, then just generate a new frame and include that instead.

[image: sample plot]

Also, since you include at least one point in both lines, I don't think it can be easily resolved with grouping. For that, I'm inferring that you would define a third variable assigning some points to specific groups. You can get around that by duplicating the offending points, as in below. You'll also need to consider the order of points:

```r
wts2 <- rbind(wts, wts[4,])
wts2$grp <- c(2,2,2,2,2,1,1)
wts2$ord <- c(1,4,2,5,3,6,7)
# original plot, just changing wts for wts2[wts2$ord,]
h <- ggplot(data=wts2[wts2$ord,], aes(x,w)) +
  geom_point(colour="blue") + 
  labs(title="Breaches",x = "Quarter", y= "Number of Breaches") +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlim(1,5) + ylim(0,120)
# an alternative to my first answer
h + geom_path(aes(group = grp, color = factor(grp)))
```

[image: sample plot 2]

Comment: That's perfect thanks!   Is there a way to add labels to each point, or even each individual line as well?

Comment: *"labels to each point"*, using `geom_text`; *"each individual line"*, `geom_text` as well at all of the points. If you want it only at specific points, add a field to the frame (e.g., `txt=c('a','','','','','','b')` and use `geom_text(aes(label=txt))`, though it'll be on top of the point; to dodge it, check out https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_nudge.html.